# What's the point of adding UseHsts() in Start.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.hstsbuilderextensions.usehsts?view=aspnetcore-2.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2), adding *UseHsts()* in the config activates the middleware for STS related header.

I've never quite understand the point of it. Does it mean nothing more than simply adding a header to each request that the application does? What can go wrong if I don't use that header?

Also, I noticed that when I try to look it up for Core 2.2 (the link above), I get redirected to Core 2.1 with the remark that *UseHsts()* isn't present in the former version. Does it mean it's been obsolete or is using a default that hides the magic?

Comment: The HSTS header prevents a browser from requesting anything from that site again in a non-secured way, what makes you think that is not useful? Also, the doc link doesn't say the info is obsolete, just that they haven't reviewed it for 2.2 - it's still very much relevant.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG .. You made me go over the stackoverflow policy on plagiarism ...

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee Are you implying that my post is a plagiarism? Not following...

Comment: @DavidG Aha, I thought that was achieved by *UseHttpsRedirection()*. Thanks for correcting me and, also, thanks for the explanation about the link/obsolete confusion. You might want to post it as a reply so I can accept it as the right answer.

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee I did not delete your answer, a moderator did. Also, really peculiar to use my full name as it's not mentioned here on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Ohh Sorry @DavidG I did not meant that it was deleted by you...will correct myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) allows a site to request that it always be contacted over HTTPS. HSTS is supported in Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, Edge and IE

Reference https://www.chromium.org/hsts

> HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) is a web security policy mechanism that helps to protect websites against protocol downgrade attacks and cookie hijacking. It allows web servers to declare that web browsers (or other complying user agents) should interact with it using only secure HTTPS connections,[1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797) and never via the insecure HTTP protocol. HSTS is an IETF standards track protocol and is specified in [RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TLS you should enable this flag. Note: Be sure you don't enable it on localhost (if you aren't using TLS on localhost). You'll be unable to load the website. You'll need to invalidate the cache on your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer doesn't actually addresses the issue being asked, though. The question isn't what it does (that's provided in the question by the linkage to the docs). I'm asking why I'd need it and what can go wrong if I don't. The reason for that is me thinking that *UserHttpRedirection()* was doing that job already. However, the point on not using it on *localhost* (which is usually done automagically by the template setting a conditional statement relying of development environment) is informative.